# Jenkins mesosphere/jenkins-dind:0.3.1 and proxy

Tags: jenkins, docker, proxy, mesos, dcos

All,
I am using DCOS and the associated Jenkins.
My company is having a proxy for any external traffic.
Jenkins is running properly and can access the internal network as well as any external network.
I can get jobs to curl a URL on internet if I set the HTTP proxy. I can pass this proxy to mesosphere/jenkins-dind:0.3.1 container as environment variable however, I can't run any docker pull or docker run while being in docker in docker mode.

I managed to reproduce the issue on one of the agent box.

sudo docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker!

This works!!
However, sudo docker run --privileged mesosphere/jenkins-dind:0.3.1   wrapper.sh "docker run hello-world" will fail with 
docker: Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images: x509: certificate is valid for FG3K6C3A13800607, not index.docker.io.

This is typically showing that the docker daemon is not having access to the proxy.

Do you know how to ensure that the dind is getting access to the proxy settings?
Antoine

Comment: It looks like you should be able to take advantage of `DOCKER_EXTRA_OPTS` https://github.com/mesosphere/jenkins-dind-agent/blob/master/wrapper.sh#L5

Comment: hello I have tried this and I can't get find the parameters to pass, I have tried -e; --engine-env and doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

This error can also manifest itself if the Docker daemon is unauthenticated against your registry but it looks like you're running against the public image, so that's not likely to be the problem.

You could try creating a new Parameter to the Jenkins node (see the instructions here for an example for how to set an environment variable called `DOCKER_EXTRA_OPTS`: https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/usage/service-guides/jenkins/advanced-configuration/).

In this case, we want to do the same (with Name `env`) but with the contents of Value set to something like `HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/`.

Comment: I have tried DOCKER_EXTRA_OPTS=-e http_proxy="http://mycompanyproxy.com:8080/" --e https_proxy="http://mycompanyproxy.com:8080/" --e no_proxy="mycompany.com,localhost,127.0.0.1/8,leader.mesos,master.mesos"  and it doesn't work

Comment: No, that's incorrect. You need to create new parameters for each of these with the Name `env` and the Value `HTTP_PROXY="mycompanyproxy.com:8080/"` (and `env` and `HTTPS_PROXY="mycompanyproxy.com:8080/"` and so on).